# There is no attribute for one object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I learned the book "programming python' these days. When I run the examples, I met the problem. The shell showed me the error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'

However, I copy the exactly code from the book. I'm a freshman of Python. I try to fix it by myself, but I failed. So I hope anyone could kindly help me.

Thanks !!!!!!

CODE：

```
#File test.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def MyGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button = Button(self, text='press', command=reply)
        button.pack()
    def reply(self):
        showinfo(title = 'popup',message ='Button pressed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyGui()
    window.pack()
    window.mainloop()

    #File test2.py
from tkinter import *
from test import MyGui

mainwin = Tk()
Label(mainwin,text = __name__).pack()

popup = Toplevel()
Label(popup,text = 'Attach').pack(side = LEFT)
MyGui(popup).pack(side=RIGHT)
mainwin.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error, not just the last line?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this with the following code:

```
#File test.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class MyGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button = Button(self, text='press', command=self.reply)
        button.pack()
    def reply(self):
        showinfo(title = 'popup',message ='Button pressed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyGui()
    window.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Basically two small syntax errors. First you were trying to make a class of `MyGui`, but you used keyword `def` which made a function instead (that returned `None`, hence the error you received.) It is syntaxically correct in python to define functions inside of functions so it was a little harder to catch. You have to use the keyword `class` to define a class.

Secondly when referencing the function `reply` you must use `self.reply` within the class itself.